# Can automapper be told that a property is ok to be left blank?

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to decide if I want to pursue Automapper as a technology to use at my company.  Before I dig in, I have a question that I want to be sure is doable with automapper.

Say I have a property in my destination class that I don't want to fill with automapper.  Is there a way to tell automapper to ignore the property and not fail when I call `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid()`?

So, for example:

```
class DTOMyObject
{
     public int Test {get; set;}
     public int Test2 {get; set;}
     public int Test3 {get; set;}
     public int Test4 {get; set;}
     public int Test5 {get; set;}
}

class ViewMyObject
{
     public int Test {get; set;}
     public int Test2 {get; set;}
     public int Test3 {get; set;}
     public int Test4 {get; set;}
     public int Test5 {get; set;}

     public int MyCustomUnMappedProperty{get; set;}
}
```

After mapping these (with `ViewMyObject` as the destination), I want to be able to call `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid()` and have it not fail if (and only if) `MyCustomUnMappedProperty` is the only one one that is unmapped.

Is there a way to do that?  If so, can you show me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Src, Dest>()
    .ForMember(d => d.MyCustomUnmappedProperty, o => o.Ignore());
```